# Plotting two objects addresses on map.how to set two different design balloons for two objects?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

```
<script> 
function drawMap(){


    var balloon = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var mapOptions = {
            center: coords[0],
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };


        con = con.replace(/[,;]$/,'');   
        var mystring =con;
        var splits = mystring.split(",");

        type = type.replace(/[,;]$/,'');   
        var mystring1 =type;
        var splits1 = mystring1.split(",");

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),  mapOptions);
        for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: coords[i], title:splits1[i]+'-'+splits[i], zIndex:i});   

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
              return function () {
              var index = this.zIndex;
               balloon.setContent('<b>'+splits1[i]+'</b><br/>'+splits[i]);
                balloon.open(map, marker);
                }
              })(marker, i));

            markers.push(marker);

        }
    }
   geocodeClientSide();
    </script>
```

In Above code Split1[i] output returns as either "account" or "lead" .
I want to keep different design images for plotting account and lead .

Currently i am getting red color balloon by default ?

How can i do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including sample data (for coords, con), any HTML/CSS required, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asmentioned in [google api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) In new google.maps.Marker().

please check this example. Here we are using two icons, 1 dotted black, and other brown.

```js
var map;

var locations  = [{
 position: {
        lat: -25.363, 
     lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/256/Maps-Location-icon.png',
}, {
 position: {
        lat: -28.363, 
     lng: 135.044,
    },
    icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/location-icon.png',
}];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 4,
    center: locations[0].position
  });
   
   for (var index in locations) {
       var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      locations[index]['icon'],
     null, /* size is determined at runtime */
     null, /* origin is 0,0 */
     null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
     new google.maps.Size(20, 20));
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: locations[index].position,
      map: map ,
           icon: image,
    });
   }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 initMap();
});
```

```css
#map {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Yes i know that we can use attribute icon for image .how can i keep two different images as i mentioned above spiltting the two objects data plotting .

Comment: `MarkerImage` was deprecated in v3.10, use `Icon` instead.